# can not find dynamic html select in code behind

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have a class named "row" that has 3 item {property,instance,degree}.
now i want to show my items or rows to user and if he changed the third part of class i edit it. this is my code of generating rows dynamically, numberOfInstance is number of rows.

```
<div id="hidden" class="hiddendiv">
<% 
 string matn = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < numberOfInstance ; i++)
 {
     row r= new row();
     r = a[i];
     matn+= " <div class='CMSdiv'>";
     matn += "<input id='Text"+i+"' class='labelhid' type='text'"+"value = '"+r.Property+ "'/>";
     matn += "<input id='Text2" + i + "' class='labelhid' type='text'" + "value = '" + r.instance+ "'/>";

     matn += " <select id='Select" +i+ "'class='drophid' runat='server'>";
     matn += " <option value= '"+ "خیلی زیاد"+"'>خیلی زیاد" + " <option value= '"+"زیاد'"+">زیاد";
     matn += " <option value='"+"متوسط'"+">متوسط";
     matn += " <option value='" + "کم'" + ">کم";
     matn += "</select>";
     matn += "</div>";
     Response.Write(matn);
     matn = "";

 }   

 %>

 </div>
```

now if user clicked on select and choose one option, i get it's value and pour to r.degree in code behind. but whatever i did i couldn't find it in code behind and was null. these are my attempts:

```
 var val = Request["Select" + i];
      string  selection = Request.Form["Select" + i];
        hd = (HiddenField)Page.FindControl("Select" + i);
  hd = (HiddenField)Control.FindControl("Select" + i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't generate server side controls by Response.Write (More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8292025/3956290)). So html elements that you are writing to output are client side controls not server side and cannot be found using the [Page.FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

Consider using one of the server side controls like [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: OK, but what can i do instead?